# Word boundary in Lucene regex

Tags: regex, elasticsearch, lucene

I'd like to a make a regex query in Elastisearch with [word boundaries](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html), however it looks like the [Lucene regex engine](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_5_0/core/org/apache/lucene/util/automaton/RegExp.html) doesn't support `\b`. What workarounds can I use?

Comment: Do you want the `4 text word and wordb` string to be returned, too (if `word` is what you are looking for)?

Comment: no, just `word`

Comment: If you are using a tokenizer, you may use Java regex. Then the `\b` is supported. See [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-pattern-tokenizer.html).

Comment: And it seems to me you might use something like `~([A-Za-z0-9_]word|word[A-Za-z0-9_])word~([A-Za-z0-9_]word|word[A-Za-z0-9_])` in the query that uses ES Lucene regex flavor, matching a string that does not contain `word`s with word chars on either end, a word, and again any text but a `word` which is a part of a word.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try.

Comment: On second thought, try `(.*[^A-Za-z0-9_])?word([^A-Za-z0-9_].*)?`

Comment: Excellent, thank you sir. Please consider making your comment an answer, and I'll be glad to accept.

Comment: Added with explanations.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In ElasticSearch regex flavor, there is no direct equivalent to a word boundary. Initial `\b` is something like `(^|[^A-Za-z0-9_])` if the `word` starts with a word char, and the trailing `\b` is like `($|[^A-Za-z0-9_])` if the `word` ends with a word char.

Thus, we need to make sure that there is a non-word char before and after `word` or start/end of string. Since the regex is anchored by default, all we need to make `[^A-Za-z0-9_]` optional at start/end of string is add `.*` beside and wrap with an optional grouping construct:

```
(.*[^A-Za-z0-9_])?word([^A-Za-z0-9_].*)?
```

**Details**

- `(.*[^A-Za-z0-9_])?` - either start of string or any 0+ chars (but a line break char, else use `(.|\n)*`) and then any char but a word char (basically, it is start of string followed with 1 or 0 occurrences of the pattern inside the group)
- `word` - a word
- `([^A-Za-z0-9_].*)?` - an optional sequence of any char but a word char followed with any 0+ chars, followed by the end of string position (implicit in Lucene regex).

Comment: What would I need to do to add certain special characters to the boundaries? Is this correct: `(.*[^A-Za-z0-9#+&=-_])?`?

Comment: My regex above also matches `[` and `?` which I don't want. How can I avoid this?

Comment: @FlorianWalther `=-_` created a range. You need to put `-` at the start of the class, `[^-A-Za-z0-9#+&=_]`

Comment: Oh, that makes a lot of sense. Thank you so much!