# What is the correct way to format regex metacharacters and options when using the regex operator in $searchBeta in MongoDB?

Tags: regex, mongodb, mongodb-atlas-search

I'm trying to do full-text search in MongoDB with $searchBeta (aggregation) and I'm using the 'regex' operator to do so. Here's the portion of the $searchBeta I have that isn't working how I expecting it would:

```
$searchBeta: {
    regex: {
        query: '\blightn', // '\b' is the word boundary metacharacter
        path: ["name", "set_name"],
        allowAnalyzedField: true
    }
}
```

Here's an example of two documents that I'm expecting to get matched by the expression:

```
{
    "name": "Lightning Bolt"
    "set_name": "Masters 25"
},
{
    "name": "Chain Lightning",
    "set_name": "Battlebond"
}
```

What I actually get:

```
[] //empty array
```

If I use an expression like:

```
$searchBeta: {
    regex: {
        query: '[a-zA-Z]'
        path: ["name", "set_name"],
        allowAnalyzedField: true
    }
}
```

then I get results back.

I can't get any expression that has regex metacharacters and/or options in it to work, so I'm pretty sure I'm just entering it wrong in my query string. The $searchBeta regex documentation doesn't really cover how to format metacharacters into your query string. Also, the $searchBeta regex operator is different from $regex because it doesn't require slashes (i.e. "/your expression/" ). Really pulling my hair out on something so simple that I can't figure out.

Answer (score 0):

`$searchBeta` uses Lucene for regular expressions, which is not Perl Compatible (PCRE) and doesn't support `\b`.  You can read about the [Lucene regex syntax here](https://lucene.apache.org/core/7_0_1/core/org/apache/lucene/util/automaton/RegExp.html) and also [Elastic's docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/regexp-syntax.html) on it are also helpful.

Here is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48517856/word-boundary-in-lucene-regex) for ElasticSearch and includes some workarounds.